# Sklearn's MinMaxScaler only returns zeros

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to scale a some number to a range of 0 - 1 using `preprocessing` from `sklearn`. Thats what i did:

```
data = [44.645, 44.055, 44.54, 44.04, 43.975, 43.49, 42.04, 42.6, 42.46, 41.405]
min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
data_scaled = min_max_scaler.fit_transform([data])
print data_scaled
```

But data_scaled only contains zeros. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: How did you fix your problem? The answers below, did not work for me.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I had the same problem when I tried scaling with MinMaxScaler from sklearn.preprocessing. Scaler returned me zeros when I used a shape a numpy array as list, i.e. [1, n] which looks like the following:

```
data = [[44.645, 44.055, 44.54, 44.04, 43.975, 43.49, 42.04, 42.6, 42.46, 41.405]]
```

I changed the shape of array to [n, 1]. In your case it would like the following

```
data = [[44.645], 
        [44.055], 
        [44.540], 
        [44.040], 
        [43.975], 
        [43.490], 
        [42.040], 
        [42.600], 
        [42.460], 
        [41.405]]
```

Then MinMaxScaler worked in proper way.

Answer (score 4):

This is because data is a int32 or int64 and the MinMaxScaler needs a float. Try this:

```
import numpy as np
data = [44.645, 44.055, 44.54, 44.04, 43.975, 43.49, 42.04, 42.6, 42.46, 41.405]
min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
data_scaled = min_max_scaler.fit_transform([np.float32(data)])
print data_scaled
```

Comment: This does not solve the questions asked. Printing data_scaled still returns the zeros

Answer (score 2):

```
data = []
data = np.array(data)
data.append([44.645, 44.055, 44.54, 44.04, 43.975, 43.49, 42.04, 42.6, 42.46, 41.405])
min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
data_scaled = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(data.reshape(10,-1))
data = data_scaled.reshape( -1, 10)
print data
```

The reason behind this is when you're trying to apply fit_transform method of StandardScaler object to array of size (1, n) you obviously get all zeros, because for each number of array you subtract from it mean of this number, which equal to number and divide to std of this number. If you want to get correct scaling of your array, you should convert it to array with size (n, 1).

See the correct answer of this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46555820/sklearn-standardscaler-returns-all-zeros) :

Answer (score 1):

They already give the right answer, but i solve my problem using the function `numpy.vstack(<your array>)`, in your problem you can write like this:

```
import numpy as np

data = [44.645, 44.055, 44.54, 44.04, 43.975, 43.49, 42.04, 42.6, 42.46, 41.405]
min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
data_scaled = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(np.vstack(data))
print(data_scaled)
#If you want to return in original format you can use 
#hstack function
data_scaled = np.hstack(data_scaled)
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You're putting your data into a list for some reason, but you shouldn't:

```
data_scaled = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(data)
```

Comment: But if i don't do that this error will occur: TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object does not support item assignment

Comment: What do `sklearn.__version__` and `numpy.version.version` say on your system?  Because the above code works for me with recent versions.

Comment: I'm using the same sklearn, NumPy 1.8.1, and Python 2.7.8 and also Python 3.4.1.  When I run the code in your question I get an array of zeros; when I use the line in my answer I get a non-zero array as expected, with the first value being 1 and the last being 0.  You should test on another system.